# Limit relationships

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have two tables I.e Order and OrderTransaction where Order to Order Transaction is one to many relationship. I have to fetch Order Transaction as relationship in Order table . How can I limit the number of Order Transaction to a specific number eg 3, rather than pulling all the transactions for the order .

```
class Order(Base): 
     orderTransactions = relationship(
        "Order", uselist=True,
        lazy="joined"
    )
```

When I fetch order based on primary key order id, I need to fetch only 3 transactions in orderTransactions relationship. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Fix for the above is using  lazy loading as dynamic.

```
class Order(Base): 
     orderTransactions = relationship(
        "Order", uselist=True,
        lazy="dynamic"
    )
```

As i need to fetch  only 3 order transactions  so whenever i need order transaction i would do like this .

```
transactions   = order.orderTransactions[0:3]
```